# How to to display the data that I have got from a form in django?

Tags: django

```
data = form.cleaned_data
rad1=form.cleaned_data['point']
```

I want to display both the data and rad1 , so as to know what is my form capturing . One way to do it send it as a value to the template to be displayed on the page . But I think there would be an easier way out . If I give a print 'data' . It doesn't print the data anywhere .

Comment: do you want show data in the form?

Comment: No I don't want to show the data in the template , if thats what you mean . I just want to know , what is in the data variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text sent to stderr will appear in the web server's error log; it is best to use either [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) or a logger supplied by the WSGI container for this.

If you want the text to appear in the browser then you will need to send it in the response, either as raw text or via a template.